# Recursive SQL query with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following columns

```
idRelationshipType int,  
idPerson1 int,  
idPerson2 int
```

This table allows me to indicate records in a database that should be linked together.

I need to do a query returning all the unique ids where a person's id exists in idPerson1 or idPerson2 columns. Additionally, I need the query to be recursive so that the if I a match is found in idPerson1, the value for idPerson2 is included in the result set and used to repeat the query recursively until no more matches are found.

Example data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbRelationships]
(
    [idRelationshipType] [int],
    [idPerson1] [int] ,
    [idPerson2] [int]
)

INSERT INTO tbRelationships (idRelationshipType, idPerson1, idPerson2) 
VALUES (1, 1, 2)  
INSERT INTO tbRelationships (idRelationshipType, idPerson1, idPerson2) 
VALUES (1, 2, 3)  
INSERT INTO tbRelationships (idRelationshipType, idPerson1, idPerson2) 
VALUES (1, 3, 4)  
INSERT INTO tbRelationships (idRelationshipType, idPerson1, idPerson2) 
VALUES (1, 5, 1)
```

Four 'Relationships' are defined here. For this query, I will only know one of the ids to begin with. I need a query that in concept works like

```
SELECT idPerson 
FROM [some query] 
WHERE [the id i have to start with] = @idPerson 
  AND idRelationshipType = @idRelationshipType
```

The returned result should be a 5 rows with one column 'idPerson', with 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 as the row values.

I have tried various combinations of UNPIVOT and recursive CTEs but I am not making much progress.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
DECLARE @RelationshipType int
DECLARE @PersonId int

SELECT @RelationshipType = 1, @PersonId = 1

;WITH Hierachy (idPerson1, IdPerson2)
AS
(
    --root 
    SELECT  R.idPerson1, R.idPerson2
    FROM    tbRelationships R
    WHERE   R.idRelationshipType = @RelationshipType
    AND     (R.idPerson1 = @PersonId OR R.idPerson2 = @PersonId)
    --recurse
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  R.idPerson1, R.idPerson2
    FROM    Hierachy H
    JOIN    tbRelationships R
            ON  (R.idPerson1 = H.idPerson2
                 OR R.idPerson2 = H.idPerson1)
            AND R.idRelationshipType = @RelationshipType
)
SELECT DISTINCT idPerson
FROM
(
    SELECT idPerson1 AS idPerson FROM Hierachy
    UNION
    SELECT idPerson2 AS idPerson FROM Hierachy
) H
```

Essentially, get the first rows where the required id is in either column, and then recurse getting all of the child ids based on id column 2

Comment: That is close but, if you use @personId=3, it does not return 1,2,3,4.  Instead it only returns 2,3,4.  If you use @personid=4, only 3,4 are returned.

Comment: I don't understand from the question why you would expect the results you describe above! Are you intending to recurse up from id1 as well as down from id2? Otherwise where would the 1 arrive from with id=3?

Comment: The table indicates relationships between individuals.  It isn't hierarchical - no parent child relationship... In this case I need to get all the relationships for that are connected either up or down the list.  When I have the id of a person, I need to know all the relationships that exist no matter how distant.

Comment: I don't think that the answers you are expecting are right - if you want all relationships then that implies that for all ids in 1 - 5 you will get all ids returned - by definition if 1 is related to 1 through 5 then all of those are related to 1 and by extension each other